# Union two models together causes "The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, union

I have a project that I am working on that currently is working for one model.  Now, I need to union another model on to that same list.  I believe I am 90% there as I have done research which has gotten me this far. However, I am receiving an error during run-time that says, "The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts."

Here is my code:

```
var unimodel = from order in uni.Orders
        select order;

var lAHmodel = from other in lah.OtherOrder
        select other;

if (searchOrders.SearchStartDate.HasValue)
{
      unimodel = unimodel.Where(o => o.OrderDate >= searchOrders.SearchStartDate);
      lAHmodel = lAHmodel.Where(o => o.OrderTime >= searchOrders.SearchStartDate);
}
if (searchOrders.SearchEndDate.HasValue)
{
      unimodel = unimodel.Where(o => o.OrderDate <= searchOrders.SearchEndDate);
      lAHmodel = lAHmodel.Where(o => o.OrderTime <= searchOrders.SearchEndDate);
}

var uniSearchResult = unimodel.Select(x => new SearchResultViewModel { OrderNumber = x.OrderId, PaymentName = x.PaymentFullName, OrderDate = x.OrderDate, Amount = x.Total, Site = "University" });
var lahSearchResult = lAHmodel.Select(x => new SearchResultViewModel { OrderNumber = x.OrderId, PaymentName = x.PaymentCardholderName, OrderDate = x.OrderTime, Amount = x.Price, Site = "Series 50" });

var SearchResult = uniSearchResult.Union(lahSearchResult);
return View(SearchResult);
```

This is the line of code where I receive the error:

```
var SearchResult = uniSearchResult.Union(lahSearchResult);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty straight-forward. You've got two contexts in play, you're querying items from both, and then trying to combine them into one. That's not possible.

However, the problem here is only that you have yet to evaluate the query. As along as you realize that separate queries will need to be made to each context, you can simply evaluate them before attempting the union. Evaluation (sending the query to the database) is done just-in-time, so it doesn't happen until you perform some action that requires the actual values from the database (iteration, casting to a list, etc.). The easiest solution here is to just tack `.ToList()` onto the end of the `uniSearchResult` and `lahSearchResult` variable declarations.

Answer (score 2):

Change these 2 lines

```
var uniSearchResult = unimodel.Select(x => new SearchResultViewModel { OrderNumber = x.OrderId, PaymentName = x.PaymentFullName, OrderDate = x.OrderDate, Amount = x.Total, Site = "University" });
var lahSearchResult = lAHmodel.Select(x => new SearchResultViewModel { OrderNumber = x.OrderId, PaymentName = x.PaymentCardholderName, OrderDate = x.OrderTime, Amount = x.Price, Site = "Series 50" });
```

to

```
var uniSearchResult = unimodel.Select(x => new SearchResultViewModel { OrderNumber = x.OrderId, PaymentName = x.PaymentFullName, OrderDate = x.OrderDate, Amount = x.Total, Site = "University" }).ToList();
var lahSearchResult = lAHmodel.Select(x => new SearchResultViewModel { OrderNumber = x.OrderId, PaymentName = x.PaymentCardholderName, OrderDate = x.OrderTime, Amount = x.Price, Site = "Series 50" }).ToList();
```

.ToList() will actually run the queries and populate your objects.  Without the .ToList() you are trying to merge 2 IQueryables which are linked to their individual contexts.